# Indexing cannot yield multiple results in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to build confusion matrix in Matlab but I'm getting this error.

```
    Indexing cannot yield multiple results.

Error in Untitled3 (line 184)
 [Max, argmax1]= max(simoutelem);
```

I want to find maximum value in this matrix and its index.I know from [enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) that `max` can be used to find the value and index of the largest element.
This is my code.
    matris=zeros(10,2316);

```
 for i=1:300
    simoutelem=Foutput(:,i);
    [Max, argmax1]= max(simoutelem);
    matris(argmax1,i)=1;
 end

 confusion=zeros(10,10);
    for i=1:10
        for j=1:26
        confusion(i,1)=((matris(i,j)+confusion(i,1)))/26; 
        end
    end
for i=1:10
     for k=2:10
        for j=(k-1)*26+1:(k-1)*26+30
        confusion(i,k)=((matris(i,j)+confusion(i,k)))/30; 
        end
     end
end
```

I also tested

```
max(simoutelem(:));
```

In the link I mentioned is an example of what I'm trying to implement:
Create a matrix A and compute the largest elements in each column, as well as the row indices of A in which they appear.

A = [1 9 -2; 8 4 -5]

A =

```
 1     9    -2
 8     4    -5
```

[M,I] = max(A)

M =

```
 8     9    -2
```

I =

```
 2     1     1
```

My whole code:

```
    TrainSet=cell(200);
TestSet=cell(30);
%zeros(n,m);
%......................................................................................
%Reading train dataset
directory=dir('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TrainSet');
for i=3:length(directory)    
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TrainSet\',directory(i).name);
    directory1=dir(folderstring);    
    for j=3:length(directory1)     
        TrainSet{i-2}{j-2}=audioread(strcat(folderstring,'\',directory1(j).name));
    end
end
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Reading test dataset
directory2=dir('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TestSet');
for i=3:length(directory2)
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TestSet\',directory2(i).name);
    directory3=dir(folderstring);
    for j=3:length(directory3)     
        TestSet{i-2}{j-2}=audioread(strcat(folderstring,'\',directory3(j).name));
    end
end
%.......................................................................................
% make files equal in size using zero padding
%find longest
max=0;
TrainSize=0;
TestSize=0;

for i=3: length(directory) 
    for j=3:length(directory1)  
         if(size(TrainSet{i-2}{j-2},1) > TrainSize)             
             TrainSize=size(TrainSet{i-2}{j-2},1);
         end   
    end  
end
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for i=3:length(directory2)
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TestSet\',directory2(i).name);
    directory3=dir(folderstring);    
    for j=3:length(directory3)     
        if(size(TestSet{i-2}{j-2},1) > TestSize)             
             TestSize=size(TestSet{i-2}{j-2},1);
  %tempsize=size(TestSet{i-2}{j-2},1);
  % TestSize=max(tempsize,TestSize);
        end   
        end  
end

if(TestSize>TrainSize)
    max=TestSize;
else
    max=TrainSize;
end

%zero padding-----------------------------------

for i=3: length(directory2) 
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TestSet\',directory2(i).name);
    directory3=dir(folderstring);
    for j=3:length(directory3)           
        m=zeros(1,max-size(TestSet{i-2}{j-2},1));        
        t=[TestSet{i-2}{j-2}',m];
        TestSet{i-2}{j-2}=t';

    end
end

for i=3: length(directory) 
    for j=3:length(directory1)   
        m=zeros(1,max-size(TrainSet{i-2}{j-2},1));
       t=[TrainSet{i-2}{j-2}',m];
        TrainSet{i-2}{j-2}=t';

    end
end

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Implementation of mlp

%newff( p,t ,[10 5], {'tansig' 'logsig'},'traingd','','mse',{},{},''); 
%net = init(net); 
%[trained_net, stats] = train(net, p, t);
%coeff = 0.2;
%

%frame=20ms-160sample
%y = buffer(window, 1, floor(64 * 0.5));
wnum=floor(max/80)-1;
w=hamming(160);
%for k=1: wnum
 %   if k==1
  %      sig=TestSet{i-2}{j-2};
   %     final(1,:)=(sig,1:160);
    %end
%end
 %--------------------------------------framing   
% finalLpc[10][190];

%...............................................Test...............
for i=3:length(directory2)
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TestSet\',directory(i).name);
    directory3=dir(folderstring);    
    for j=3:length(directory3)     
          %cats=[];
          lpcTest=[];        
        for k=1 :wnum
           sig1=TestSet{i-2}{j-2};
           if k==1              
        framTest=sig1(1:160);
           else
            framTest=sig1((k-1)*80+1:((k+1)*80)); 
           end
           winTest=framTest.* w;  
           cats1=lpc(winTest,12);
       catss1(k,:)=cats1(2:13); 

        end        
        features1=12*(floor(max/80)-1);
        %features=2316
        n=length(directory3);  
      anninput1((i-3)*(length(directory3)-2 ) +(j-2),:) =reshape(catss1,1,2316);
    end
end
%.............
anninput1=anninput1';
%...............................................Train..................
for i=3:length(directory)
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\Rihanna\Desktop\TrainSet\',directory(i).name);
    directory1=dir(folderstring);    
    for j=3:length(directory1)     
          %cats=[];
          lpcTrain=[];        
        for k=1 :wnum
           sig=TrainSet{i-2}{j-2};
           if k==1              
        framTrain=sig(1:160);
           else
            framTrain=sig((k-1)*80+1:((k+1)*80)); 
            %((k-1).*80)+1 :(k+1).*80
           end
           winTrain=framTrain.* w;  
           cats=lpc(winTrain,12);
       catss(k,:)=cats(2:13); 

   % lpcTrain =[lpcTrain,l];
        end        
        features=12*(floor(max/80)-1);
        %features=2316
        n=length(directory1);  
          anninput((i-3)*(length(directory1)-2 ) +(j-2),:) =reshape(catss,1,2316);
 %input(i*(190)+(ii),:)=reshape(l_effective,1,2316);
   % finalLpc{i-2}{j-2}=lpcTrain;
   %1900*2316
    end
end
%...............................ANN...............................................................
input=anninput';
output=[zeros(10,190) ones(10,190) repmat(2,10,190) repmat(3,10,190) repmat(4,10,190) repmat(5,10,190) repmat(6,10,190) repmat(7,10,190) repmat(8,10,190) repmat(9,10,190) ];
net=newff(input,output,1158);
net=init(net);
%Learning rate
net.trainParam.lr=0.2;
net.trainParam.showWindow=1;
net.trainParam.min_grad=0;
net.trainParam.mem_reduc=50;
net.efficiency.memoryReduction = 60;
net= trainrp(net, input,output);

%plot_xor(net);


%...............................................

Foutput=sim(net, anninput1); % Returns one output.
%figure, plotconfusion(Foutput, sim(net,input));


matris=zeros(10,2316);

 for i=1:300
    simoutelem=Foutput(:,i);
    [Max, argmax1]= max(simoutelem);
    matris(argmax1,i)=1;
 end

 confusion=zeros(10,10);
    for i=1:10
        for j=1:26
        confusion(i,1)=((matris(i,j)+confusion(i,1)))/26; 
        end
    end
for i=1:10
     for k=2:10
        for j=(k-1)*26+1:(k-1)*26+30
        confusion(i,k)=((matris(i,j)+confusion(i,k)))/30; 
        end
     end
end
```

Comment: So do you have multiple max-value and you want to find all of them? In that case use find(v==max(v))

Comment: I want to find maximum value in this matrix and its index.

Comment: Ok, so what is wrong with `max`? Use this for value: `max(max(A))` and this for index `find(A==max(max(A)))`

Comment: I added some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error tells me that you've defined a variable `max` somewhere in your code.

> Indexing cannot yield multiple results

Why? Because otherwise `[Max, argmax1]= max(simoutelem);` wouldn't be taken as a case of "Indexing".

Easy proof at command line:

```
[a b] = max([1 2 3 4 5]) % works
max = 1:100;
[a b] = max([1 2 3 4 5]) % gives your error
clear max
[a b] = max([1 2 3 4 5]) % works again
```

Comment: Yes I have! I will add my complete code. But the max I have defined are in local scope out of this loop.

Comment: Yes it seems it's not in local scope! So I just have to rename max?

Comment: *Never* name a variable the same as a basic function like `max` that is asking for trouble.  A for loop is not a separate function so there's no "local scope" here.  (Don't believe me? Put `which max` right after `simoutelem=Foutput(:,i);` and before you try to call `max` as a function).

Comment: Thank you... I'm new to MATLAB. In other languages like C you are not allowed to do that, but MATLAB doesn't give you error.